# Setting up PC as a wired VPN gateway

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, lan

Hi i am looking at using a vpn service.
I have a home server running windows 10 which i want to put the vpn client on and have the other computers on the lan use this server as a router to access the internet so that they all use the vpn connection.

There is no WIFI involved at all just ethernet. I have been looking online and cannot find a way to do this that doesn't use wifi. I have found a linux version for a raspberry pi that would do what i want (https://github.com/mr-canoehead/vpn_client_gateway) but would prefer to have it on my main windows server.

To put it simply i would really like to know how to set up the pc as a vpn client gateway and i then presume i just need to change the dns server adresses on the client computers, and it will acces the internet through the vpn?

Thank you i have spent hours searching online to no avail.